# Increase Stack Size in Dev C++ permanently

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow, dev-c++

In order to implement DFS on a huge graph in Dev c++ on a Windows 7 machine, I needed to increase the default stack size of 1 MB to 16 MB. I accomplished the same by creating a bat file in the folder as that of project with the text as..

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,16777216 -o project2.exe main.cpp
```

Every time I compile the program in Dev C++, it assigns the default stack value. I have to externally run this bat file and then run the exe file which consumes a lot of time.

Is there any way to directly add this command following the commands of compilation?

I tried adding this line in the Makefile but then the program doesn't compile.
I also tried adding it in compiler options but still comes the same issue.

Please suggest a method.

Comment: You could also make your program keep track of the search progress using a stack of your own in the data segment, instead of on the return stack.  (This basically means converting your program to use iteration instead of recursion.)

Comment: Tools->Compiler options? (from a 1 second google search...)

Comment: @MarkJansen I have already tried that. Please refer the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to install the thing, but it refused to compile a default application on default settings.... May i suggest to switch to something decent like Visual Studio?

Comment: @MarkJansen.. Your suggestion is true but I am novice guy in programming and dealing with VS will be like a mess for me..
So I chose Dev C++ in the first place..