# Process exited with return value 3221225725 - quicksort worstcase with malloc crashing, how to solve? – C

Tags: c, quicksort

I made program that measure time of sorting n data arrays of `int`. Unfortunately my quicksort in worst case around 30000 numbers in array crashing program with return value 3221225725. For average case it works fine even for 500000 numbers (that is my max for testing).

Here is code for quicksort:

```
int part(int *tab, int left, int n)
{
    int first = tab[left], i = left, j = n;
    while (0 != 1)
    {
        while (tab[j] > first)
        {
            j--;
        }   
        while (tab[i] < first)
        {
            i++;
        }
        if (i < j)
        {
            swap(&tab[i], &tab[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else 
            return j;
    }
}

void quick_sort(int *tab, int left, int n)
{
    int pivot;
    if (left < n)
    {
        pivot = part(tab, left, n);
        quick_sort(tab, left, pivot);
        quick_sort(tab, pivot + 1, n);
    }
}
```

And here is code in for loop for data cases:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "algorytmy.h"
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    clock_t czas1, czas2, czas3;
    FILE *fw;
    if (!(fw = fopen("danedowykresu_odwrotnie_zestaw2cd.txt", "w")))
    {
        printf("Blad otwarcia zbioru\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    fprintf(fw,"Liczba danych;quicksort;shellsort;heapsort\n");
    printf("Liczba danych;quicksort;shellsort;heapsort\n");
    for(n = 25000; n < 500000; n += 1000)
    {
        int tab[n], i;
        int *ptr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            ptr[i] = n - i;
        
        czas1 = clock();
        quick_sort(ptr, 0, n);
        czas1 = clock() - czas1;
        free(ptr);
        
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            tab[i] = n - i;
        czas2 = clock();
        shell_sort(tab, n);
        czas2 = clock() - czas2;
        
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            tab[i] = n - i;
        czas3 = clock();
        heap_sort(tab, n);
        czas3 = clock() - czas3;
        
        fprintf(fw,"%d;%f;%f;%f\n", n, ((float)czas1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, ((float)czas2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, ((float)czas3) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("%d;%f;%f;%f\n", n, ((float)czas1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, ((float)czas2) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, ((float)czas3) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);  
    }
    fclose(fw);
    return 0;
}
```

[console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGwAC.png)

Comment: Please do not add links to pictures of text. Instead simply copy the text into your question directly. Also please provide minimum complete example to reproduce your problem. Your fragments are not sufficient to be compiled.

Comment: This seems like a good time to learn how to use a *debugger* to catch crashes, and use it to help you locate when and where the crash happens in your program. A debugger will also let you examine variables and their values to help you see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: `int tab[n]` This can go up to ~2MB for 32 bit `int` type. Are you sure the stack is large enough? you might try to use a static variable of maximum size instead of this VLA. ... Or simply remove it as you already have `malloc` in place?

Comment: @Gerhardh Ok, i will edit code, i am using tab[n] for shellsort and heapsort and it works well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in my devc++ debugger is not working

Comment: When the C library offers *qsort()* why don't you use it?

Comment: @tofro probably an exercise.

Comment: 3221225725 or 0xC00000FD is the error number for a stack overflow on Windows, and with a worst case the recursion depth is probably too deep. You can mesure the recursion depth easily by adding 2-3 lines of code.

Comment: @tofro Cuz I must have my own

Comment: Shellsort and Heapsort used probably less or no recursion depth using less stack.

Comment: The default stack size on Windows is just 1MB which is not much nowadays. You can increase the stacksize of your executable but I have no idea how to do this with devc++, but check this anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967592/increase-stack-size-in-dev-c-permanently

Comment: Dev-C++ is old, outdated and unmaintained. There are other modern and maintained, both free and open-source, for example [Code::Blocks](https://www.codeblocks.org) (or perhaps even Microsoft Visual Studio Community, if you're on Windows).  I suggest you upgrade to an environment that works, including things like debugging (which is an integral and mandatory part of programming).

Comment: @Jabberwocky so how can I manage to shallow recursion depth?

Comment: Ok so i will try to run it in my Linux PC

Comment: @KonradStolarz either increase the stack size (see my previous comment) or instead of naive recursion use your own "stack" but that's less trivial.

Comment: What is the `pocz` variable in `quick_sort`?

Comment: Google _quicksort without recursion_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is incorrect: it is unclear what you are testing with `if (pocz < n)`.  A pure implementation would test `if (n - left > 1)`. The `part()` function has problems too: `i` and `j` are not properly initialized. It is always a good idea to verify correctness before even trying to measure performance.

The problem with quicksort worst case is you recurse too deep and eventually encounter a **stack overflow**.

Here is a modified version using a simple way to prevent deep recursion: only recurse on the smaller half and iterate on the larger one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "algorytmy.h"

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int part(int *tab, int left, int n) {
    int pivot = tab[left];
    int i = left;
    int j = n - 1;
    for (;;) {
        while (tab[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (tab[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i < j) {
            swap(&tab[i], &tab[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        } else {
            return j + 1;
        }
    }
}

void quick_sort(int *tab, int left, int n) {
    while (left + 1 < n) {
        int p = part(tab, left, n);
        if (p - left < n - p) {
            quick_sort(tab, left, p);
            left = p;
        } else {
            quick_sort(tab, p, n);
            n = p;
        }
    }
}

int check_sorted(const int *ptr, int n, const char *name) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (ptr[i - 1] > ptr[i]) {
            printf("%s failed: ptr[%d] = %d > ptr[%d] = %d\n",
                   name, i - 1, ptr[i - 1], i, ptr[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double czas1, czas2, czas3;
    FILE *fw;

    srand(time(NULL));

    if (!(fw = fopen("danedowykresu_odwrotnie_zestaw2cd.txt", "w"))) {
        printf("Blad otwarcia zbioru\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    fprintf(fw,"Liczba danych;quicksort;shellsort;heapsort\n");
    printf("Liczba danych;quicksort;shellsort;heapsort\n");

    for (int n = 25000; n < 500000; n += 1000) {
        int *ptr = malloc(n * sizeof(*ptr));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ptr[i] = n - i;
        czas1 = clock();
        quick_sort(ptr, 0, n);
        czas1 = clock() - czas1;
        check_sorted(ptr, n, "check_sorted");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ptr[i] = n - i;
        czas2 = clock();
        shell_sort(ptr, n);
        czas2 = clock() - czas2;
        check_sorted(ptr, n, "shell_sorted");

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            ptr[i] = n - i;
        czas3 = clock();
        heap_sort(ptr, n);
        czas3 = clock() - czas3;
        check_sorted(ptr, n, "heap_sorted");

        fprintf(fw,"%d;%f;%f;%f\n",
                n, czas1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, czas2 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, czas3 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        printf("%d;%f;%f;%f\n",
                n, czas1 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, czas2 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, czas3 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        free(ptr);
    }
    fclose(fw);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed code to english before posting here i didn't catch this one in if